# Determining past tweet frequency / time interval for a trending keyword

Tags: twitter, data-mining

I'm doing some work with trend detection in twitter, and I'm looking to get data regarding tweet frequency for a time period before and after before the topic becomes trending.

I know I can use the streaming API to collect real-time data, but that would require apriori knowledge of whether a certain keyword would trend, which isn't very reliable.

Lets say i knew that a certain keyword "foo" became trending on September 3rd (just an arbitrary date). I want to access data regarding tweet frequency n hours before it is marked as trending and n hours after its marked as trending.

There probably isn't a way to directly access historical data, but i figured there's no harm in asking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually *tried* keeping the aggregated historic count data? Shouldn't be that much on the 1% sample feed! A few megabytes per day, nothing scary when compressed.

Comment: If you discard any rare word (e.g. mentioned only once or twice) then the data gets much smaller, too.

Comment: well, the problem is that i would not have prior knowledge of what keywords would trend (as i want to study the activity before the keyword trends as well)

Comment: Just store *every* word, keyword that occured more than once.